# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in joomla solution without changing ini file

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I'm created a Joomla extension in which i'm storing records from table A to table B. My script is working fine if table A contains less data.
If table A contains large amout of data. While inserting this huge data execution is getting exceed & showing this error 'Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 
/mysite/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysqli.php on line 382'. 
I can overcome this problem by making change in ini file, but its Joomla extension which people gonna use it in their site so i can't tell them to make change in ini file infact i don't wanna tell them.

Comment: Very good, you explained the situation, now add a question ;)

Comment: Dear dbf didn't you get my question after reading above eassy. BTW i want to execute my code without change in ini file.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't process the table data in batches?

Comment: middaparka Can you please elaborate..?

Answer (score 0):

take a look into this

http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

use this way or

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below codes at the start of the page where you wrote the query codes
       **set_time_limit(0);**

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can increase the maximum execution time using [`set_time_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). Personally, I wouldn't mess with limits other people set on their servers, assuming they put them in for a reason (performance, security - especially in a shared hosting context, where software like Joomla! is often found). Also, `set_time_limit` won't work if PHP is run in safe mode.

So what you're left with is **splitting the task** into multiple steps. For example, if your table has 100000 records and you measure that you can process about 5000 records in a reasonable amount of time, then do the operation in 20 individual steps.

Execution time for each step should be a good deal less than 30 seconds on an average system. Note that the number of steps is dynamic, you programmatically divide the number of records by a constant (figure out a useful value during testing) to get the number of steps during runtime.

You need to split your script into two parts, one that finds out the number of steps required, displays them to the user and sequentially runs one step after another, by sending AJAX requests to the second script (like: "process records 5001 to 10000"), and marking steps as done (for the user to see) when the appropriate server respone arrives (i.e. request complete).

The second part is entirely server-sided and accepts AJAX requests. This script does the actual work on the server. It must receive some kind of parameters (the "process records 5001 to 10000" request) to understand which step it's supposed to process. When it's done with its step, it returns a "success" (or possibly "failure") code to the client script, so that it can notify the user.

There are variations on this theme, for instance you can build a script which redirects the user to itself, but with different parameters, so it's aware where it left off and can pick up from there with the next step. In general, you'd want the solution that gives the user the most information and control possible.